# Rabbit MQ - Recovery of connection/channel/consumer

Tags: c#, rabbitmq

I am creating a consumer that runs in an infinite loop to read messages from the queue. I am looking for advice/sample code on how to recover abd continue within my infinite loop even if there are network disruptions. The consumer has to stay running as it will be installed as a WindowsService.

1) Can someone please explain how to properly use these settings? What is the difference between them?

```
NetworkRecoveryInterval 
AutomaticRecoveryEnabled
RequestedHeartbeat
```

2) Please see my current sample code for the consumer. I am using the .Net RabbitMQ Client v3.5.6.

How will the above settings do the "recovery" for me? 
e.g. will consumer.Queue.Dequeue block until it is recovered?
That doesn't seem right
so...

Do I have to code for this manually? e.g. will consumer.Queue.Dequeue throw an exception for which I have to detect and manually re-create my connection, channel, and consumer? Or just the consumer, as "AutomaticRecovery" will recover the channel for me?

Does this mean I should move the consumer creation inside the while loop? what about the channel creation? and the connection creation?

3) Assuming I have to do some of this recovery code manually, are there event callbacks (and how do I register for them) to tell me that there are network problems?

Thanks!

```
public void StartConsumer(string queue)
{
            using (IModel channel = this.Connection.CreateModel())
            {
                var consumer = new QueueingBasicConsumer(channel);
                const bool noAck = false;
                channel.BasicConsume(queue, noAck, consumer);

                // do I need these conditions? or should I just do while(true)???
                while (channel.IsOpen &&        
                       Connection.IsOpen &&     
                       consumer.IsRunning)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        BasicDeliverEventArgs item;
                        if (consumer.Queue.Dequeue(Timeout, out item))
                        {
                            string message = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(item.Body);
                            DoSomethingMethod(message);
                            channel.BasicAck(item.DeliveryTag, false);
                        }
                    }
                    catch (EndOfStreamException ex)
                    {   
                        // this is likely due to some connection issue -- what am I to do?
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {   
                        // should never happen, but lets say my DoSomethingMethod(message); throws an exception
                        // presumably, I'll just log the error and keep on going
                    }
                }
            }
}

        public IConnection Connection
        {
            get
            {
                if (_connection == null) // _connection defined in class -- private static IConnection _connection;
                {
                     _connection = CreateConnection();
                }
                return _connection;
            }
        }

        private IConnection CreateConnection()
        {
            ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory()
            {
                HostName = "RabbitMqHostName",
                UserName = "RabbitMqUserName",
                Password = "RabbitMqPassword",
            };

            // why do we need to set this explicitly? shouldn't this be the default?
            factory.AutomaticRecoveryEnabled = true;

            // what is a good value to use?
            factory.NetworkRecoveryInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5); 

            // what is a good value to use? How is this different from NetworkRecoveryInterval?
            factory.RequestedHeartbeat = 5; 

            IConnection connection = factory.CreateConnection();
            return connection;
        }
```

Answer (score 30):

#### RabbitMQ features

The [documentation on RabbitMQ's site](https://www.rabbitmq.com/dotnet-api-guide.html) is actually really good. If you want to recover queues, exchanges and consumers, you're looking for *topology recovery*, which is enabled by default. Automatic Recovery (which is [enabled by default](https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-dotnet-client/blob/master/projects/RabbitMQ.Client/client/api/ConnectionFactory.cs)) includes:

- Reconnect
- Restore connection listeners
- Re-open channels
- Restore channel listeners
- Restore channel `basic.qos` setting, publisher confirms and transaction settings

The `NetworkRecoveryInterval` is the amount of time before a retry on an automatic recovery is performed (defaults to 5s).

Heartbeat has another purpose, namely to identify dead TCP connections. There are [more to read about that](https://www.rabbitmq.com/heartbeats.html) at RabbitMQ's site.

#### Code sample

Writing reliable code for recovery is tricky. The `EndOfStreamException` is (as you suspect) most likely due to network problems. If you use the [management plugin](https://www.rabbitmq.com/management.html), you can reproduce this by closing the connection from there and see that the exception is triggered. For production-like applications, you might want to have a set of brokers that you alternate between in case of connection failure. If you have several RabbitMQ brokers, you might also want to guard yourself against long-term server failure on one or more of the servers. You might want to implement error strategies, like requeuing the message, or using a dead letter exchange.

I've been thinking a bit of these things and written a thin client, [RawRabbit](https://github.com/pardahlman/RawRabbit), that handles some of these things. Maybe it could be something for you? If not, I would suggest that you change the `QueueingBasicConsumer` to an `EventingBasicConsumer`. It is event driven, rather than thread blocking.

```
var eventConsumer = new EventingBasicConsumer(channel);
eventConsumer.Received += (sender, args) =>
{
    var body = args.Body;
    eventConsumer.Model.BasicAck(args.DeliveryTag, false);
};
channel.BasicConsume(queue, false, eventConsumer);
```

If you have topology recovery activated, the consumer will be restored by the RabbitMQ Client and start receiving messages again.
For more granular control, hook up event handlers for `ConsumerCancelled` and `Shutdown` to detect connectivity problems and `Registered` to know when the consumer can be used again.

Comment: thanks for the detailed response. I think you are correct, the QueuingBasicConsumer is not the way to go, will take a look at EventingBasicConsumer.